# How to move the cursor in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to move the cursor in a DataGridView?

No. `.Selected = true;` as this puts the cell in blue by default.
I want the cursor to move when I click on "Add" button, I want the cursor to move to the last row and last column

I use :

```
this.dGridView.Rows[nbr].Cells[0].Selected = true;
this.dGridView.BeginEdit(true);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: "it doesn't work" is the *worst* way you can describe a problem. You get a compiler error? Runtime exception? Unexpected output? What?

Comment: I don't have exception or error, but the first cell is selected in blue. i want only the cursor to move

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will give you what you want, but you can change the selection background and foreground colors to negate the normal, default appearance of a cell being selected.  Get the DataGridViewCell Style property.  Then change the Style's SelectionBackColor and SelectionForeColor.